# AWS Lambda Not Triggered When Invoked via Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working on an AWS Lambda function, and due to the 30-second timeout constraints, I cannot use API Gateway to trigger it. Instead, I have set up an Application Load Balancer (ALB) to route traffic to the Lambda. Here are the steps I've followed and the current issue:

1. I created a Target Group and an Application Load Balancer.
2. I routed all traffic from the Load Balancer to the Target Group, which contains the Lambda.
3. The Target Group health check shows the Lambda as healthy.
4. However, when I send a request to the Load Balancer's DNS name (xxxxx.amazonaws.com), the Lambda function does not get triggered.
   To test the setup, I issue a request to the URL xxxxx.amazonaws.com/help/generate, expecting the Lambda to be triggered, but there is no indication that it runs.

What I have tried:

- Checked the CloudWatch logs for the Lambda to confirm it's not being triggered.
- Verified the health of the Lambda via the Target Group health check.
- Ensured that the security groups and NACLs allow traffic from the ALB to the Lambda.
- Put the lambda in the same VPC as the ALB

I am wondering what I might be missing or doing wrong that prevents the Lambda from being triggered by the ALB. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Presume the Lambda function has enough permissions to actually make logs. Does the Lambda monitoring dashboard reflect the invocation and an increased error count?

Comment: @jarmod the lambda does have permission to make logs because I can see some logs from the health check. I can also see some logs when i trigger the lambda via API Gateway.

However when i trigger it via Application Load Balancer, I see no logs

Comment: There are ALB logs. What do they show? Also, what does the HTTP response from the ALB contain or does the request time out?

Comment: @jarmod the ALB do not log. Only the health check logs. Also, the http request to ALB times out

Comment: ALBs can create [logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html). If you have logging enabled but no logs are present then perhaps your request did not actually reach the ALB.

Comment: @jarmod I think you are right. How can I ensure that my requests reach the ALB?
the DNS name is xxxxxx-0000000.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. I set up an HTTP listener on port 80 whose default action is forwarded to the target group that contains the lambda.

Comment: Can you DNS-resolve the ELB hostname? Cam you create a TCP connection to the ALB on port 80 e.g. using telnet or curl?